# Alpine asking to accept self signed certificate

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, email

I've just installed Alpine on my Debian box and transferred my configuration over from my Ubuntu machine. The configuration works perfectly on my Ubuntu machine but on the Debian box I get an error saying I have to accept the self signed certificate.

My current configuration looks like this (I've censored my email address, but I am using Gmail):
[image]

This is the error I get:
[image]

Comment: It seems unlikely that `imap.gmail.com` would be using a self-signed certificate. (1) does that address resolve _on this computer_ to the correct addresses? (2) is there a "transparent" firewall trying to intercept your network connection? (3) You haven't said, but did your old (Ubuntu) server also note that the imap server had a self-signed certificate?

Comment: HI. Thanks for commenting. Yes, both my Ubuntu machine and the Debian box are resolving imap.gmail.com to the same address. They're both directly connected to the same home network. I'm not sure if it matters, but I have ufw running on the Debian box. I tried to disable it, but I got the same error. I never had the self-signed certificate issue on the Ubuntu.

Comment: Install openssl if not already present and try this: `openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | egrep 'Issuer:|Subject:'`. Here I get `Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1` + `Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = imap.gmail.com` If you get something not similar, then you probably didn't connect to google.

Comment: Thanks. I already have OpenSSL installed, tried to run your command and I get the same output as you @A.B

Comment: If Issuer != Subject then by definition it's not a self signed certificate. Either Alpine does something else, or the error message isn't quite the correct error